# SharePoint (2010): Field for (multi) currency...?

Tags: sharepoint, currency

old problem now getting new. Anyone has a good idea for storing currency values in a sharepoint list? Problem is - there is a currency field, but it is not multi-currency enabled.

I could obviously store the value in two fields (currency lookup from a list, value in second field), but I take it as wondering whether there is a more viable approach that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own custom field type

- [Custom Field Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx)
- [Building Custom Field Types in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919.aspx)